# get(int index) method in java

Tags: java, indexing, methods

I am trying to do a get(int index) method that returns the element at the specified index in a list but I can't see what to return. What shall I have after tempNode in the end?

```
public E get(int index) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
    Node tempNode = head;
    if (index < 0 || index >= size) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("index was out of bounds");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        tempNode = tempNode.getmNextNode();
    }
    return tempNode.;
}
```

I am using the Node class:

```
public class Node<E> {
    private E mElement;
    private Node<E> mNextNode;

    Node(E data) {
        this.setmElement(data);
    }
    public E getmElement() {
        return this.mElement;
    }
    public void setmElement(E element) {
        this.mElement = element;
    }
    public Node<E> getmNextNode() {
        return this.mNextNode;
    }
    public void setmNextNode(Node<E> node) {
        this.mNextNode = node;
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you expect?

Comment: `.value`, I would guess, or `.data`? This is for a linked list, right? Return the data contained in the nth node.

Comment: I tried it but it said: Cannot resolve symbol 'data'

Comment: You should use the node methods getMElement()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a `getmElement()` method on `Node` that will return the data you want.

However, currently your `get(int)` method is using a raw `Node` variable, so there's no way to ask it for the appropriate return type.  Currently `tempNode.getmElement()` will just return an `Object`.

What you need to do is use a `Node<E>` like so:

```
public E get(int index) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
    Node<E> tempNode = head;
    if (index < 0 || index >= size) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("index was out of bounds");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        tempNode = tempNode.getmNextNode();
    }
    return tempNode.getmElement();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd return `mElement` of type `E`. That the list is build out of nodes is an implementation detail. So return `return tempNode.eElement` or rather `tempNode.getmElement()` if you cannot access it directly due to the access modifiers of the field.

Don't know what you were expecting to return otherwise.

Note that because of the `m` in there, Java will probably not recognize it as a `get` method. That's not a good idea, in Java you don't use identifiers like that, remove the `m`s from your identifiers!